# Excel VBA - Runtime error 1004 (RefreshAll fails)

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro to refresh my workbook (recalc values, refresh links, etc).

The code to refresh links works fine but when it hits the `RefreshAll` I get the following error.

```
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:="F:\klanten.xlsm", Type:=xlExcelLinks
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

[image]

All help is appreciated!

Comment: From VBA help, for `RefreshAll` *Objects that have the BackgroundQuery property set to True*. Perhaps you want to `Calculate` instead?

Comment: So ActiveWorkbook.Calculate? Well I have VLOOKUPS, etc that I want to 'update'.

Comment: try `Application.CalculateFull` - it will calculate all open workbooks in that Excel instance

Comment: thanks, just found that too. if you like post it as an answer, if not I will just delete this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than a `RefreshAll` option you are looking for a `Calculate` option

I suggest you use `Application.CalculateFull` to calculate all formulae

This link from Charles Williams on [Excel Calculation Methods](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsg.htm) may prove useful

Comment: Unclear why this was downvoted given OP explicitly stated that it was the issue.